# How to make Edittext size stay put? Android

Tags: android, size, android-edittext

I know the attribute which makes the text "disapear" on the left part of the Edittext to maintain a single line, (singleLine="true"). But my issue is when I fill the edittext before the view is displayed... in this case, my edittexts are all going out of the screen...
any ideas?
thx!

This is what is get when fill the empty Edittext. Everything stays put, and the text is vanishing on its left side

[Screenshot](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?1f6d9de832.png)

and when I prefill from my DB

[Screenshot](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?87a63b1b21.png)

here is the code of the edittext :

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/InscripChampNom"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="14px"
android:inputType="textPersonName" android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
android:singleLine="true" android:textColor="@color/background"></EditText>
```

The tableLayout is defined as follows:

```
<TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:stretchColumns="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

I also tried with the attribute

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

and

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

no success at all...

Maybe there is a conflict between input type and singleline?

**EDIT  Here is the full code of my issue :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:scrollbars="vertical" android:background="@color/backgroundzen"
android:layout_gravity="fill" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:paddingLeft="6dip"
android:paddingRight="6dip">
<TableLayout style="@style/LayoutWhiteBgrdFillWrap"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip" android:paddingRight="6dip"
    android:stretchColumns="1">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/NomFormationConference" style="@style/textViewTitleRedzenBold"
        android:text="Nom conférence"></TextView>
    <TableRow android:layout_margin="2dip">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/DateSession" android:textColor="@color/textezenrouge"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="date début"></TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/speakerConf" android:textColor="@color/textezenrouge"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="speaker"></TextView>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_margin="2dip">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/InscripNom" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/background" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/nom" android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/InscripChampNom"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip" android:hint="@string/nomh"
            android:singleLine="true" android:textColor="@color/background"></EditText>
    </TableRow>
```

//The last tablerow is repeated 5 times with various data inside.

The style is like that :

```
<style name="LayoutWhiteBgrdFillWrap">
    <item name="android:background">@color/backgroundzen</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
</style>
```

And here is how I fill the `EditText` :

```
misc = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com.mobile.zen/databases/" + Constants.UNVERSIONNED_DATABASE, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    Cursor c = misc.query("MISC", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            nomInscrit.setText(c.getString(1));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
    misc.close();
```

Comment: well I put them but they aren't displaying.
thx pentium. (why can't I display img here?)

Comment: huh, that's weird. What code/xml you have for that EditText?

Comment: Could you show us a bit more of your XML file? Or maybe how you're filling the EditText from your database? Using a TableLayout with fill_parent and stretchColumns="*" with a TextView and then an EditText with the same XML as yours, it's working fine for me. By the way, and please don't be offended by this, but when you wrote "the text is vanishing on th left side", were you confusing left and right? I was a bit puzzled by what you meant at first :p  (left == gauche, right == droite)

Comment: I'm perfectly ok with my left and right lol. When I write in an Edittext with the singleLine attribute, the text you are writing is disappearing on the left side of the so called edittext isn't it?
I have very little time these days, but I'll come back with more information in a few days.
thanks ugys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `android:shrinkColumns="1"` to your `TableLayout` to tell it that it can force the `EditText` items to be smaller to fit into the width of the screen.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your answer. You refer to column 1 but speaks of the TextView...Which one should I use?

Comment: The column numbers are zero-based, so column 1 is the second column -- the one containing your TextView widgets.  Thus, setting that attribute on the `TableLayout` affects those.

Comment: Indeed, setting the shrinkColumns="1" (the column with the EditText being the source of the issue) did the trick. Thanks VERY MUCH. I owe you 100 reput. But I can't find the bounty button anymore...

Comment: The bounty expired (they last a week), so your hundred points have evaporated.  Best you can do now is click the checkmark by the answer to accept it, which is good for 15.  Glad to help though.  I edited the answer to change the widget name, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You have no `android:layout_width` attribute on your `EditText`. Add one or otherwise constrain how long the field can be (e.g., if it is in a `RelativeLayout`, use `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`).

Comment: it's not working ... I tried wrap_content and fill_parent as width, but none worked.
These edittext are in a tablelayout with the strech column applied to their column.. if it can help...

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to reproduce your issue but I couldn't.

Check this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/a" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14px" android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip" android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"></EditText>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/b" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14px" android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip" android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"></EditText>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/c" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14px" android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip" android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"></EditText>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Ok, wait, I'll update my first post with full code so that you can see.

Comment: Did this give you any inspiration?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a possible bug in Android. But one way to solve it may be is to specify some value as a width to the Edit Text box and specify

> android:stretchColumns="1"

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:scrollbars="vertical" android:background="#ffffff"
android:layout_gravity="fill" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:paddingLeft="6dip">
  <TableLayout android:layout_below="@+id/reltable1" android:id="@+id/tablelayout_main" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_marginRight="10dip" android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:gravity="center" android:stretchColumns="1">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/NomFormationConference" 
        android:text="Nom conférence"></TextView>
    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/DateSession"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="date début"></TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/speakerConf" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="speaker"></TextView>
    </TableRow>
      <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/InscripNom" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="nom" android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/InscripChampNom"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="nomh" android:text="dsfdsfdsfsdfsdfsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:layout_width="220dip" android:ellipsize="end"></EditText>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I have also Added height and width property for TableRow

Answer (score 0):

i don't think tablelayout works in scrollview.
i had a setup as such and it does not throw errors
but the emulator just does not load the app and says stopped working.
i removed the scrollview and thing started working.

i think the problem is that tablelayout has its own scroll bars
it does not need scrollview and perhaps the two conflict.

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/InscripChampNom"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="14px" 
    android:inputType="none" 
    android:layout_marginRight="20dip" 
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:textColor="@color/background" 
    android:editable="false"
    android:ellipsize="end">
</EditText>
```