# EditText height changes according to the text size

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-edittext, text-size

If I change the textsize in editext, the height of edittext changes accordingly.  I want the size of edittext to be same and I want a smaller sized hint or text to be in it. What should I do? Following is the code and I am also posting the screenshot of this layout :

```
  <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/normal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#4594e4"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/set"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/bari" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etOrigin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_35sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/set"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/set"
                android:background="#5fa7f1"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="My Location"
                android:textColor="#434343"
                android:textIsSelectable="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etDestination"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/etOrigin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_35sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/set"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/set"
                android:background="#5fa7f1"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:onClick="wow"
                android:text="Where to go ?"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textColorHint="#fff" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/swipe"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="27dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/flip" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Screenshot of the layout before changing:

[image: Screenshot of the layout before changing]

Screenshot of layout after changing textsize:

[image: Screenshot of layout after changing textsize]

Comment: use padding in edit text

Comment: I will prefer padding..

Comment: use edittext min height or set fix height.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Edittext size stay put? Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522369/how-to-make-edittext-size-stay-put-android)

Comment: got it guys . Thank you ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use padding for this :-**

```
         <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etOrigin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_35sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/set"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/set"
            android:background="#5fa7f1"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="My Location"
            android:textColor="#434343"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" />
```

Comment: How does it work? I think, it simply adds padding, but doesn't set a height for any font size.

Comment: @CoolMind it was handle by android

Comment: @AbhinavGupta, it only adds paddings. It doesn't set a height. So, if we change a text size, the EditText's height will change.

Comment: @CoolMind yes it will change because default textSize have 16sp if you increase more than 16sp height will change according to textsize ....

Answer (score 4):

Try using `android:minHeight` and `android:maxHeight` attributes :

```
                            <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/etUserName"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:hint="@string/hint_username"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:inputType="textPersonName"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
                            android:maxHeight="?actionBarSize"
                            android:textColor="@color/textPrimary"
                            android:textSize="12sp"/>

                            <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/etUserEmail"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:hint="@string/hint_username"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
                            android:maxHeight="?actionBarSize"
                            android:textColor="@color/textPrimary"
                            android:textSize="14sp"/>
```

Comment: Wc mate! Thanks for your appreciation as well

Comment: Thanks! `minHeight` is enough.

Comment: Wc mate! Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 2):

Give fix height to the layout  `android:layout_height="75dp"`

```
            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etOrigin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_35sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/set"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/set"
            android:background="#5fa7f1"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="My Location"
            android:textColor="#434343"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
```

Comment: Thats what i don't want to do actually. I want it to be adjustable on all devices

Comment: Then write style for it and give fix different height for every screen size. 
like for hdpi android:layout_height="75dp" for mdpi android:layout_height="60dp" xhdpi android:layout_height="90dp"

Answer (score 2):

Here, try this third party library.
Your TextView height would be fixed but your textView size will be adjusted

```
dependencies {
    compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
}
```

Enable any View extending TextView in code:

```
AutofitHelper.create(textView);
```

Enable any View extending TextView in XML:

```
<me.grantland.widget.AutofitLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        />
</me.grantland.widget.AutofitLayout>
```

Use the built in Widget in code or XML:

```
<RootElement
    xmlns:autofit="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ...
<me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    autofit:minTextSize="16sp"
    />
```

For more information, visit below link:

https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly set the height and size of your `EditText` view as well as the text in it.

To set the heigh of the `EditText` simply use :

```
android:layout_height="<height_you_want>dp"
```

And to set height of the text in your `EditText` view :

```
android:textSize="<height_you_want>sp"
```

And you can simultaneously view the changes in the preview tab of AndroidStudio.

Comment: I know this but in that case if the device is of higher resolution or of bigger screensize, the layout height will remain same which i want to change according to the screensize.

Comment: In that case, you might wanna see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dip-dp-and-sp). Just as a summary, the unit `dp` is `density independent pixel` and it would scale perfectly on screens with different pixel-densities, which mostly represent the size (resolution) of the screen

Comment: And you can create different layouts for `mdpi`, `ldpi`, `hdpi`, `xhdpi` and `xxhdpi` if that is a big concern. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507609/image-resolution-for-mdpi-hdpi-xhdpi-and-xxhdpi)

Comment: I knew about mdpi and hdpi etc but didnt knew that dp is density independent. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

One Solution : include these two lines in your XML file

android:maxLines="1"
android:singleLine="true"

Answer (score 0):

Using the `EditText` inside of a `ConstraintLayout` will fix this.

```xml
...
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="17">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"                        
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="1"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="foo"
    />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```